# How to assign local variable to global in Firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a global variable I want to it to be assigned to the local variable to be passed to another function, but whenever I assign it, in the end I get a nil then the program is crashing. In swift 5

I want to assign urls to the in closure url

```
        // Donwload the URL

        storageReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
                self.errorLabel.text = "Error in download url"
                return
            }
            guard let u = url?.absoluteString  else { return }
            self.urls = u
        }
```

Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

this is what I get !

Comment: can you show more code? For example where the global variable is defined, how you assign a new value, and how you try to get the variable?

Comment: Your global variable is nil why dont you assign it a value before using or passing it any where or even assigning it to anyother variable.